# Optimal strategies in a simple game when facing gambler's ruin

Tags: probability, game-theory, random-walk, stopping-times, gambling

Suppose we have the following game that's free to play. The game consists of an infinite number of stages, where in each stage you must bet your entire bankroll to quadruple it with probability $3/4$ and lose it with probability $1/4$. You may stop playing the game anytime you wish and collect your winnings, and you are given 1 unit for free to play with in the first stage.

My question is: what's the best strategy for when to stop? Each stage of the game has positive expected value when considered alone, as we win $4b$ with probability $3/4$ and lose $b$ with probability $1/4$, so that the EV is $(11/4)b$, where $b$ is our bankroll. However, in the long run we will lose almost surely, and so the "correct" strategy can't be to just play whenever playing is positive expected value.

I've considered "double or nothing" strategies, where we fix a value $n$ and stop playing only when we have earned at least $n$. This gives us a new random variable $X_n$, whose expected value will be

$$n\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{\log_4(n)}$$

as we reach our desired level after $\log_4(n)$ rounds of quadrupling and earn $n$. However, this goes to infinity, and so again it seems that the "optimal" strategy in terms of expected value is to keep going for double or nothing until we bust.

I'm sure this has a simple resolution (or maybe it's a special case, since this theoretical game is far from fair). Given this game, when should we stop playing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of a correct strategy? (Your use of scare quotes seems to indicate that perhaps you don't have one? In that case, what exactly is the content of your question?)

Comment: I want a strategy that maximizes the expected value of our winnings. What's tripping me up is that it seems that any strategy that seeks to maximize the expected value will reduce down to "keep playing forever", but if we do that, we will eventually lose and earn nothing. I guess I'm looking for a way to resolve what seems to be this paradox.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion there. The expected value of which winnings do you want to maximize? As you have correctly stated, the expected value at any given stage of the game is maximized by always continuing to play. But at any given stage of the game there is a finite probability not to lose; so there's no paradox. That we lose with probability $1$ is a statement about an infinite game.

Comment: But this infinite game doesn't have an expected value; the winnings in this infinite game are not even real-valued; they're infinite with probability $0$ and zero with probability $1$. So there's no paradox there, either. What you perceive as a paradox seems to arise because you're not clearly distinguishing between the finite games and the infinite game.

Comment: If the winnings are useful I suggest You read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox#Expected_utility_theory and search for more on the subject. If they are just a highscore, why not play forever?